# Return to Previous Url MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I started learning MVC and i am stuck in this problem.

I have an Order Details page in which I have a button "Edit". When the user clicks on it, opens up a Bootstrap Modal, which i called from a Partial View.
Now Modal opens up and shows the data, loaded from database and saves the data to database.

Everything is working just fine.

I just want the user to go back to that Specific Detail Page from where He/She clicked "Edit" Button.

For example
Detail Page URL is
**../orders/details/2**

form saves at
**..order_detail/edit/[id]**

after form submit it should go back to
**../orders/details/2**

How can i achieve this?
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: are you using ajax.Beginform on submit of Edit button? you can use var siteUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower(); to get the prevoius url and redirect to previous page

Comment: i'm using Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning on your current View after executing post method you can redirect to the action you want, passing the id. For example:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("YourDetailsActionHere", new { id = id});
}
```

And if your action is in different controller you have to pass the controller name as well

```
return RedirectToAction("YourDetailsActionHere", "YourOtherController", new { id = id});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have 2 default MVC functions of Edit. Get and Post. In GET function i have the ID which i can pass to redirect but on POST function i don't.
I know it must be simple solution but i can't seem to figure it out.